# How to get calculated element width and height in YUI3?

Tags: jquery, dom, yui

jQuery has handy .height() and .width() utilities to get calculated displayed size of a DOM element. It also has .position() to get coordinates. In [YUI3 Node](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/api/Node.html), I see that there are .getX(), .getY() and .getXY() utilities to get position, but I do not see anything for size (or can't look).

What's a good way to get element height and width in YUI3?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[getComputedStyle](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/api/Node.html#method_getComputedStyle)

```
.getComputedStyle("width")
.getComputedStyle("height")
```

Comment: The returned value of .getCOmputedStyle is string like "940px" which can be turned into int by parseInt.

Comment: Just so long as you remember to pass in a radix of 10!

Comment: @Tivac the returned value is not going to be starting with "0" or "0x", so it's not a big danger here. But of course, it's good to remember about that quirk.