# what is the jQuery outerHeight() equivalent in YUI

Tags: javascript, jquery, height, yui

In jQuery, I can very easily get the current computed height for an element that includes padding, border, and optionally margin by using [outerHeight()](http://api.jquery.com/outerHeight/)...

```
// returns height of element + border + padding + margin
$('.my-element').outerHeight(true);
```

How would I do this in YUI? I'm currently using **version 2.8.1**.

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4136616/yui-get-true-element-width), I can always do [getComputedStyle()](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/api/classes/Node.html#method_getComputedStyle) for height, border, padding, and margin, but that is a lot of manual labor which includes parsing the return values and grabbing the correct values that are needed and doing the math myself.

Isn't there some equivalent function to jQuery's `outerHeight()` in YUI that does all of this for me?

### Solution

I ended up writing my own solution since I couldn't find a jQuery `outerheight()` equivalent. I've posted the solution as [an answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12753203/196921).

Comment: Have you tried `.get("offsetHeight")`?

Comment: I believe `offsetHeight` does not include the margin values, which are important to me

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3039828/how-to-get-calculated-element-width-and-height-in-yui3

Comment: just a heads up, if your margin is in %, the outerHeight value in safari is incorrect for jquery

Comment: thanks for the heads up. it should always be in pixels, but i'll make sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up writing my own little utility function for this:

```
/**
 * Calculates the outer height for the given DOM element, including the 
 * contributions of padding, border, and margin.
 * 
 * @param el - the element of which to calculate the outer height
 */
function calculateElementOuterHeight(el) {

  var height = 0;
  var attributeHeight = 0;
  var attributes = [
      'height', 
      'border-top-width', 
      'border-bottom-width', 
      'padding-top', 
      'padding-bottom', 
      'margin-top', 
      'margin-bottom'
  ];

  for (var i = 0; i < attributes.length; i++) {

    // for most browsers, getStyle() will get us a value for the attribute 
    // that is parse-able into a number
    attributeHeight = parseInt(YAHOO.util.Dom.getStyle(el, attributes[i]), 10);

    // if the browser returns something that is not parse-able, like "auto", 
    // try getComputedStyle(); should get us what we need
    if (isNaN(attributeHeight)) {
      attributeHeight = parseInt(YAHOO.util.Dom.getComputedStyle(el, attributes[i]), 10);
    }

    // if we have an actual numeric value now, add it to the height, 
    // otherwise ignore it
    if (!isNaN(attributeHeight)) {
      height += attributeHeight;
    }
  }

  return isNaN(height) ? 0 : height;
}
```

This seems to work across all modern browsers. I've tested it in Chrome, Firefox (idk about 3.6, but the latest version works), Safari, Opera, & IE 7,8,9. Let me know what you guys think!

Answer (score 5):

There is no built-in way of getting the outer width of an element with its margin in YUI. Like @jshirley mentions, there is `offsetWidth`, but it doesn't take margins into account. You can however create a function that adds the margin very easily:

```
Y.Node.ATTRS.outerHeight = {
  getter: function () {
    return this.get('offsetHeight') + 
           parseFloat(this.getComputedStyle('marginTop')) + 
           parseFloat(this.getComputedStyle('marginBottom'));
  }
};

Y.Node.ATTRS.outerWidth = {
  getter: function () {
    return this.get('offsetWidth') +
           parseFloat(this.getComputedStyle('marginLeft')) +
           parseFloat(this.getComputedStyle('marginRight'));
  }
};
```

Then you can get the outer width by doing `Y.one(selector).get('outerWidth')`. Here's an example based on @jshirley's code: http://jsbin.com/aretab/4/.

Just keep in mind that dimensions are usually a source of bugs in browsers and this doesn't take into account some stuff (ie: dimensions of the document) jQuery tries to catch (see https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/dimensions.js).

Comment: I just noticed he said he was using YUI 2. The above solution is a very good one, however is for YUI 3. There are no real valid reasons for using YUI 2 in this day and age.

Comment: no real valid reasons? if I had it my way, I'd be using jQuery, but I can't... reasons above my pay grade ;)

Answer (score 2):

If you wanted to avoid the manual labor, wrap the element in a div and get the computed style of that.

If it's something you're doing more than once, create a function/plugin to reuse.

Answer (score 1):

According to http://www.jsrosettastone.com/, you should be using .get('offsetHeight').

This example shows the equivalency: http://jsbin.com/aretab/1/edit

Comment: this does not work. this does not include the `margin` of the element.

Comment: I'm using `outerHeight(true)`... passing in `true` tells jQuery to use margin in its calculation