# Finding HTML element pixel dimensions from Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, dom, cross-browser

I'm looking for a solid, cross-browser way of finding the following calculated dimensions from Javascript:

- content rectangle: innermost content area
- client rectangle: content area + padding
- complete rectangle: content + padding + border + margin

It doesn't have to be exactly that grouping, I'm just looking for enough info to completely decompose any box into content->padding->border->margin segments.

(I probably won't have to care about scroll bars, but if they have a well-defined behaviour as well, I wouldn't mind knowing that)

I want to be able to get these as *pixel* values, regardless of how they were styled from CSS. So even in the case of e.g. `margin-left: auto` or `width: 50%`, I want to be able to extract the computed results in pixels.

No jQuery solutions please, I'm looking for vanilla Javascript + DOM answers.

Comment: Did you manage to solve the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery way of doing it would be to call .outerWidth() or .outerHeight(). In not being able to use jQuery, you could take a look into the [jQuery source](http://docs.jquery.com/Source_Code) to see how they achieve this.

Alternatively, there are a few answers here which yield the same results. E.g.: [what is the jQuery outerHeight() equivalent in YUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12680638/what-is-the-jquery-outerheight-equivalent-in-yui/12753203#12753203) & [outerWidth without jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5195402/outerwidth-without-jquery).

From the latter:

```
document.getElementById('container').offsetWidth; // "Outer" Width
document.getElementById('container').clientWidth; // "Inner" Width
```

With .offsetHeight and .clientHeight for heights, respectively.

Comment: Use `$('#elementId').innerHeight()` and `$('#elementId').innerWidth()` for the content width.

Comment: Actually, both innerWidth() and outerWidth() includes padding, with outerWidth() also including border and optionally margin.

Frankly, I was hoping I wouldn't have to sift through the entire jQuery source to find these answers; surely someone else must have done this without jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

This may help:

```
<style>
  body { 
    margin: 10%;
    padding:10px 0 0;
    border:1px solid #000;
  }
</style>

var elem = document.body;

var computedStyle = window.getComputedStyle ? getComputedStyle(elem, '') : elem.currentStyle;

var marginTop = computedStyle.marginTop;
var borderTop = computedStyle.borderTopWidth;
var paddingTop = computedStyle.paddingTop;
console.log(marginTop);
console.log(borderTop);
console.log(paddingTop);
```

// for me returns 168px, 1px, 10px

But it returns percents for IE < 9. For older versions you should transform percents to pixels (you can find more here http://erik.eae.net/archives/2007/07/27/18.54.15/#comment-102291)

Comment: Looks like you're on to something here... I'll give this a go when I revisit the problem.